# Concat values of an immutable map in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, immutable.js

i'm having an immutable map like this:
`pinMap = Map({pin1: 1}, {pin2: 2}, {pin3: 3}, {pin4: 4})`. Now i want to create an objct as follows:
`obj = {pinCode: 1234}` whose value is the merged values of the map. I've tried the following command:
`const obj = {obj: {...pinMap.values()} }` with no success. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your map was created as string: number pairs,

```
  let pinMap = new Map();
  pinMap.set("pin1", 1); //Assuming these are numbers
  pinMap.set("pin2", 2);
  pinMap.set("pin3", 3);
  pinMap.set("pin4", 4);
```

Map has a couple of ways to iterate over the map. For ease, we can use the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) iteration method

```
  let pinCode = "";
  pinMap.forEach((value) => {
    pinCode = pinCode + value.toString();
  });

  let result = {
    pinCode: pinCode
  };
```